# MYSQL row count is NULL but I need to display 0

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple row count in PHP.
When no rows are found, I need $sfideRicevute to be '0', but this query returns me nothing.

*PHP:*

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `match` WHERE show_id = $showid AND w02 = $id AND status = 'sfida'";

    if ($result = mysql_query ("$sql")){
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array ($result)) {

?>
<? $sfideRicevute = mysql_num_rows($result); ?>
<? echo $sfideRicevute; ?>
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: This looks terrifyingly insecure because your user parameters are not [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You should **NEVER** be putting `$_POST` data directly into the query. This creates a gigantic [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). Also, `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used, it's being removed from PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Comment: Considering you're not testing for errors, who knows what could be going wrong here. PDO, if used correctly, will raise exceptions if there's every any problems so you won't miss any errors.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo intval($sfideRicevute);
```

or

```
echo (int) $sfideRicevute
```

Both cast the value to integer 0. In php '0', false, 0, null will all be converted to int 0 this way.

1, true and other numbers will keep their value however, I don't know if that's clear right away :)

Please review http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php for more information.

Answer (score 2):

From PHP docs what mysql_num_rows returns:

> The number of rows in a result set on success or FALSE on failure.

It should be returning 0, if it isn't, there's likely something wrong with the query.

Also note that using these mysql_ functions are not recommended, since they are going to be removed from php, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated

Second: have you thought about SQL injections, as you are putting a variable into the query directly, which also isn't recommended and not necessary with the alternatives mentioned in the link above.

Comment: I disagree, even if a query fails execution. User feedback should be 0 rows or something like no results. mysql_num_rows will also be false if the database is offline for example. Also, props for raising the SQL injection.

Comment: What exactly are you disagreeing on? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check to see what the value of $sfideRicevute is and if it's null, display 0.

```
echo $sfideRicevute == null ? 0 : $sfideRicevute;
```